# Clickatell messages only delivered when message contains word "test"

Tags: sandbox, clickatell

I've set up a Sandbox SMS environment using the new API and I have registered a test phone number. I'm successfully sending messages but only messages with the word "test" are being delivered.

Is this a requirement of the Sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case not.
I was trying to delete words Test+message+text, and all works fine.
My SMS request looks like so:

```
https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=FeKBZwZ3T2q3BNcjsJvHCA==&to=1234567&content=How are you Darko?
```

After I paste this into my Chrome web browser, I got the message with content "How are you Darko?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You posted your API key in your answer. I hope you change your API key.

Comment: My API key does not functionning any more. You need to change to your API key.